# nullable Promise with a non-nullable payload + unwrapper function infers `unknown` instead of the payload type

Tags: typescript

This example fails to compile on Typescript 4.9:

```js
interface Wrapper<T> {
    wrapped: T;
}

const p: Promise<Wrapper<string>> = Promise.resolve({ wrapped: 'foo' });

async function unwrap<T>(value: Wrapper<T>): Promise<T>;
async function unwrap<T>(value: Wrapper<T> | undefined): Promise<T | undefined>;
async function unwrap<T>(value: Wrapper<T> | undefined): Promise<T | undefined> {
    return value?.wrapped;
}

const foo: string = await p.then(unwrap);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOpTgB09APAFQD5kBvAKGUuQHcNsIATALmXwG4yBfMshAexABnMMkwsAClD4BbYIIi50WHFFzCooAOaFiAXmSSZciADooEQXwA2ANwgAKEjTo5myAOQw+fd8k4BKDjI4QQBPEARkGABXCLBgAWRY2iwCQnsbOCtoiBYlelUifwkpWXk0jhDwyJi4hJAkkBTMNIysnLyXPCJkAB9GhggYUEZig1LjAj6BoZGGQkqwiKjYhHjE5LpWzOzctC7C4n7YweGQUZKjcvxpk9nz+dIKKnMwaKgGnZyAfhNm1w43F4AmEUW8LHUWmQ+jg1DgwBEmBMYAAFhAQPZNlhAjwAPS45CCYBWdFIZColD8aSYYnQZBwEAMZBWUCQKBkGx8YAMexePg4iAAD0wfCgIhInDYQA)

The compiler states (about `foo`) that

```
Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

and inspecting the inferred type for `.then` shows

```
Promise<Wrapper<string>>.then<unknown, string>(
  onfulfilled?: ((value: Wrapper<string>) => unknown) | null | undefined, 
  onrejected?: ((reason: any) => string | PromiseLike<string>) | null | undefined,
): Promise<...>
```

(formatted slightly for convenience)

I don't understand why it's inferring `unknown` as the resolved value type parameter. The overload including `| undefined` seems to be at fault, as removing it allows the function to type-check properly... except that I can no longer use this function for the other intended usage, that is:

```
const p: Promise<Wrapper<string> | undefined> = Promise.resolve(undefined);
const foo: string | undefined = p.then(unwrap);
```

Which complains, predictably, about `unwrap` that

```
Type 'Wrapper<string> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Wrapper<string>'.
```

How can I type this function correctly? I want to avoid polluting calling code with null checks when the Promise has a non-null payload, but I want to be able to conveniently use it for nullable-payload Promises too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a lambda:

```ts
const foo: string = await p.then(wr => unwrap(wr))
```

Compare:

```ts
const prString = p.then(wr => unwrap(wr))
```

- the compiler knows p is a `Promise<string>`
- thus it infers wr to be `Wrapper<string>`
- thus it correctly picks the overloaded version of unwrap

With:

```ts
const f = unwrap
const prUnknown = p.then(f)
```

- compiler does not know which overload of unwrap to pick
- f is typed as

```
const f: {
    <T>(value: Wrapper<T>): Promise<T>;
    <T>(value: Wrapper<T> | undefined): Promise<T | undefined>;
}
```

Comment: "compiler does not know which overload of unwrap to pick": but why? If you strip all the async stuff from the examples, it chooses the correct overload depending on if `undefined` is present in the input union. Same goes for the trampoline (?) lambda you define. What about `then`'s signature makes passing the function directly not work?